# Javascript changing select box selected value not working properly

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am using javascript to programmatically add options to an html select box. When I add a new option, I am setting that option's .selected property to true so that it is the one that appears in the select box. When I do this, the innerHTML does not change to the new value, but when I click in the select box, I see the option I wanted selected has a checkmark next to it, indicating it is selected.  Why isn't the value shown the correct value?

Here is my function that populates the select box options:

```
function printCartList(newCart){
    // Check if newCart is null
    newCart = newCart ? newCart : "a_new_cart_was_not_provided_12345abcde";

    // set carts object from cookie if it exists, otherwise create a new one
    if($.cookie("carts") != null){
        carts = JSON.parse($.cookie("carts"));
    }
    else{
        selectOption = new Object();
        selectOption.value = "newuniquecartid12345abcde";
        selectOption.html = "***New Cart***";
        carts = new Object();
        carts.size = 1;
        carts.option = new Array();
        carts.option[0] = selectOption;
    }

    // Get the select element
    var select = document.getElementById("select_cart");

    // Get the length of the select options list
    var length = select.options.length;

    // Remove all items from the select box
    while(select.options.length > 0){
        select.remove(0);
    }

    // If newCart was provided, create a new option and add it to the cart
    if(newCart != "a_new_cart_was_not_provided_12345abcde"){
        selectOption = new Object();
        selectOption.value = newCart;
        selectOption.html = newCart;
        carts.option[carts.size] = selectOption;
        carts.size++;
    }
    // Save the cart in a cookie
    $.cookie("carts",JSON.stringify(carts));

    // Add the options to the select box
    for(var i = 0; i < carts.size; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = carts.option[i].value;
        opt.innerHTML = carts.option[i].html;
        if($.cookie("activeCart") == carts.option[i].value){
            // Set the option to true if the cart is the active cart.
//*****I have tested this with an alert box showing the value of carts.option[i].value    This is being called for the correct option*******
            opt.selected = true;
        }
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }   
}
```

The new item is being added to the select box, and does have a checkmark next to it when viewing all the items in the select box, it just doesn't show the correct value in the select box.

Here is my html:

```
<form method="POST" name="cartSelectForm" action="home.php">
    <select name="cartList" id="select_cart" data-mini="true" onchange="submitCartForm()" data-icon="false">
        <option value="newuniquecartid1234567890">*** New Cart ***</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

***edit***

I have discovered that jquery css is interfering with javascript filling the innerHTML of the select box.  I am linking in: "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css".  Is there anyway to get around the jquery?  I can't just remove the jquery css.  That would break everything on my site, and I don't have time to redo it all.

Here is a jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RjXRB/1/

Comment: To motivate people to offer solutions try to find the smallest code that reproduces the issue and try to make a working example in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar.

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding this to a jsfiddle, but it works properly. I guess there must be something else outside the above code causing the issue. Although I don't have a clue where.

Comment: So i have discovered that I am linking in jquery css <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />).  This is interfering with the innerHTML of the select box being displayed.  Is there any way to get around the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use angular way when creating select box - look here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

```
  <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name group by c.shade for c in colors">
  </select>
```

If you have a reason to use the innerHtml approach, you should consider using `Scope.apply` or `Scope.$digest` as described  [in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).

Comment: *Why* is that 'better'?

Comment: because then there are no DOM synchronization issues between angular and the "outer" world